# Fat Free Framework 3.5 conditional routes in .ini format

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I've defined my `routes.ini` file with several entries like this:

```
[routes]

GET /=PublicController->home
GET /login=PublicController->login
GET /logout=PublicController->logout
POST /auth=PublicController->auth
[...]
```

I was wondering if it's possibile to dynamically modifiy routes depending on arbitrary conditions to check, e.g. session variables and so on.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
if ($f3->get('SESSION.user.level') == 'admin') {
    GET /=AdminController->home
} else {
    GET /=UserController->home
}
```

within an .ini file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. 
But surprisingly you can use php for this:

```
if ($f3->get('SESSION.user.level') == 'admin') {
    $f3->route('GET /','AdminController->home');
    $f3->config('admin.ini');
} else {
    $f3->route('GET /','UserController->home');
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly. But that means I'll have to either retire my cool-as-hell .ini file and create a normal .php container, or cast route definitions in multiple locations, which is not exactly the nicestest thing I can think of. Am I right?

Comment: F3 ini files follow the general INI file syntax: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file there are no conditions here per definition. If you would add logic to your ini file, how would it be that different from a php file? if you need that, maybe think about loading multiple different config files matching your conditions. nevertheless you can add some dynamic tokens to the ini like `GET /={{@context}}Controller->home` if you use the $allow parameter http://fatfreeframework.com/base#config

Comment: @ikkez, you could add this in your answer as this feature is little known. Also there's the possibility to control the inclusion of additional config files directly from the .ini file using the `[configs]` section. E.g: `{{@context}}.ini = TRUE` would include either `user.ini` or `admin.ini`, depending on `@context`. Similarly, `{{@extra}}.ini = TRUE` would include an extra ini file *if and only if* `@extra` is set to an existing file name and would silently fail otherwise.

Comment: Dynamic tokens are nice, but perhaps a little complicated to digest. I fancy the idea of multiple .ini files based on a controller lever evaluated condition more. Nice hints by the way, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using a slightly different approach, and thought I'd share it as-well.

In my main index.php file I look for the url component, and load the routes (and overload other config setting) according to that

```
if(explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1] === "admin"){
    $f3->config('../f3/app/config/config.admin.ini');
    $f3->config('../f3/app/config/routes.admin.ini');
}
```

I use this instead of the Session, because the controllers used in the router can handle redirection to the login page. You also can continue using routes in ini file, which I prefer.